# Round Function Erratic -- Micropython

Tags: rounding, micropython

I am working with an MPU-6050 3-axis accelerometer and using this code to read the current Z axis value with 1/10 second between readings:

az=round(imu.accel.z,2) + 0.04 (0.04 is the calibration value)

print(str(az))

Most times the value displayed with the print statement is correct (i.e., 0.84). But sometimes the value printed is the full seven-decimal place value (0.8400001). Is there a way to correct this so the two-decimal place value is displayed consistently?

Comment: Will rounding `az` again after addition of calibration value work?           
`az=round(imu.accel.z,2) + 0.04 (0.04 is the calibration value)`                
`az=round(az,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, perform math with calibration value and round after

```
az=round(float(imu.accel.z) + 0.04,2)
print(str(az))
```